# AbstractFacade is not working on all entities

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

In NetBeans I used "Entity Classes from Database" to create classes based on the tables from such database. No problem here. To be specific, let's take two tables: Employee and Client. Both have SSN (primary key); first name; and last name. The only difference is that client has as foreign key the SSN of a Employee.

Next, I used "Session Beans for Entity Classes" so I can use queries to work with the database. Among the facades that are automatically created is AbstractFacade. Let's focus on the method:

```
public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}
```

As far as know, and how I was recently taught, with this I can find any entity where its primary key matches with this "id". And in fact, if I use:

```
Employee employee = employeeFacade.find(SSN);
```

And it works. However, when I try the equivalent for Client, it throws an exception. Then I tried to do it with "brute force" and tried the next custom method:

```
try {
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.ssn = ?1", Employee.class);
    Employee employee = query.setParameter(1, ssn).getSingleResult();
            
    return employee ;
}  catch (NoResultException ex){
    return 0;
}
```

Employee works perfectly, but Client throws NoResultException with it's equivalent method. The same if I find by first name or last name, and I don't understand why. The same might happen with the rest of the tables on the database.

Comment: Have you checked if your database actually has the expected record?